# How to Fix Xcode's Code Indentation Mistakes?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, indentation

I always place `{` and `}` on empty lines.

Xcode wrongly indents code blocks with this formatting preference, when editing code or when reformatting a selection using tapping Ctrl-I.

If I for example enter return to move the `{` to the next line in:

```
VStack {
    Text("Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious")
}
```

the result will be:

```
VStack
    {
    Text("Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious")
}
```

Or, if I select and then Ctrl-I the following code:

```
VStack
{
    Text("Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious")
}
```

it will result in this indentation mess:

```
VStack
    {
        Text("Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious")
}
```

Does anyone know a way how Xcode can be made to behave and understand this alternative, yet common (and sensible), code indentation format?

I've reported this to Apple: #FB7343322.